# I cannot authenticate to Firebase Auth with the mobile network, only with Wi-Fi, why is this happen? Android Kotlin Compose

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am implementing authentication with Firebase Auth, everything is fine using WIFI, but when I want to try it over the mobile network, I can't and it doesn't show even an error. Please help me, this is the code:

This is the code inside a viewmodel

```
fun login(email: String, password: String, onSuccess: () -> Unit){
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                showProgressBar = false
                onSuccess()
                Log.d("Login", "User login")
            } else {
                Log.d("Login", "Error user login")
                showProgressBar = true
                showAlert = true
            }
        }
}
```

This is the code inside the login button

```
scope.launch {
    showProgressIndicator = true
    delay(timeDelay)
    loginViewModel.login(email, password) {
       navController.navigate(NavigationViews.Home.Wells.route){
            launchSingleTop = true
            popUpTo(NavigationViews.Login.route){
                 inclusive = true
            }
       }
   showProgressIndicator = loginViewModel.showProgressBar
   }
}
```

I was analyzing, could it be something with the android compose navbar?

I have tried to move the viewmodel code inside the button and it still doesn't work.

Comment: So does the authentication work when using mobile data?

Comment: Nope just with WIFI Connection :(